# how to link SimpleMembership UserProfile to an extended profile with foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

I have run out of ideas on how to make this code work in the way i want it to. I have 3 models as noted below.

`UserProfile and Player` **one-to-one relationship**

UserProfile is created first, at registration emailConfirmation is sent to user's email provided. Once they confirm their account, they are redirected to their first login page, if authenticated, redirected to a Create a new player page to provide more information on their extended profile. On the create page, i want the `UserId` of the logged in User to be the same for the about to be created player. When i try the code as is, there is no response and nothing is added or save to the database.

`Team and Player` **one-to-many relationship**

Pretty much self explanatory, a player must belong to a team. This makes redirect to Edit action a no go as `Player.TeamId != null`.

**UserProfile**

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

**Team**

```
    public class Team
    {
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }         

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }        
}
```

**Player**

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string FullName{ get; set; }        

    [Display(Name = "Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
 }
```

**SavePlayer**

```
public void SavePlayer(Player player)
    {
        using (var context = new EFootballDb())
        {
            if (player.UserId == 0)
            {
                context.Players.Add(player);
            }
            else if (player.UserId > 0)
            {
                 var currentPlayer = context.Players                        
                    .Single(t => t.UserId == player.UserId);

                context.Entry(currentPlayer).CurrentValues.SetValues(player);                    
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Create action**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateTeamsDropDownList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Player model)
    {
       try
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
                _dataSource.SavePlayer(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Team", new { id = model.TeamId });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
        PopulateTeamsDropDownList(model.TeamId);
        return View(model);
    }


private void PopulateTeamsDropDownList(object selectedTeams = null)
    {
        var teamsQuery = from d in _dataSource.Teams
                         orderby d.Name
                         select d;
        ViewBag.TeamID = new SelectList(teamsQuery, "TeamId", "Name", selectedTeams);
    }
```

Everything works just fine bewteen `Team and Player` but i just can't get `UserProfile and Player` to link up at Creation. Does anyone have ideas or different approach i should try? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I am adding another way to do this.  This is a very complex way, it works but in the end you will not want this.

This one is a pain.  I too spent a lot of time figuring this out.  The closest online resource that I found was [here](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model).

Note there are two errors on that page.
1) Use Add-Migration instead of Create-Migration
2) When updating the UsersContext make sure to include the generic type for the DbSet.  I.E.

```
public DbSet<Membership> Membership { get; set; }
```

Follow the steps on that link.  Then you will need to go a bit more.

For my solution I moved all the models to a Model Class Library and the UsersContext to a DAL Class Library, but this is not required.

Once you have finished the migration you can add a basic class to link to the UserProfile like so ...

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to update the UsersContext. NOTE: You can rename UsersContext to whatever you like.

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

The last step is to add a class that is called in your AccountController in place of the WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(...)

```
public class CustomSimpleMembershipProvider
{
    private readonly UsersContext _db = new UsersContext();

    public bool CreateUser(string username, string password, string firstName)
    {
        var userCreated = false;

        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);

        var userProfile = _db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);

        // Check if user already exists
        if (userProfile != null)
        {
            var member = new Model.User { FirstName = firstName, UserProfile = userProfile };

            try
            {
                _db.Users.Add(member);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                userCreated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Add logging or throw whatever exceptions needed
                throw;
            }

        }
        return userCreated;
    }
}
```

The reason for the migration is it allows you to control the membership tables in your own context.  I have tried to create them in separate contexts without success.  I hope this gets you what you need.

Comment: This hasn't worked out for me. I tried several ways, but no luck yet. Only adds and saves the UserProfile and nothing else

Comment: Komenge, When the UserProfile is saved and you look at the database structure, does it look correct with the relationship between your UserProfile and related table?  Also, in the try on saving the related object, do you get an exception?

Comment: So far, i can tell that UserProfile and other related membership tables are updated. I have no column in UserProfile to hold data for Player as i am getting UserProfile's UserId and passing it to Player as foreign key. I think `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` or any related calls are coming up null. I think it has something to do with the context i am using which differes from what WebSecurity is using.

Comment: No exception is thrown, and i do have exceptions in place if data is not saved.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  Your player data must be added separately.  Use the class CustomSimpleMembershipProvider that I detailed above, instead of User, you will add your Player table data.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to do this is just create a class with a virtual foreign key to the UserProfile.  Virtual is for lazy loading.  The reason I did it this way is once I got to the OAuth it worked much easier.

```
   public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int UserProfileId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

Then move your UsersContext out of the AccountModels.cs into your custom Context like this.

```
public class OAuthNoMigrateContext : DbContext
{
    public OAuthNoMigrateContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Create a similar CustomSimpleMembershipProvider as in my other answer.

```
public class CustomSimpleMembershipProvider
{
    private readonly OAuthNoMigrateContext _db = new OAuthNoMigrateContext();

    public bool CreateUser(string username, string password, User user)
    {
        var userCreated = false;

        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);

        var userProfile = _db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);

        // Check if user exists
        if (userProfile != null)
        {
            user.UserProfile = userProfile;

            try
            {
                _db.Users.Add(user);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                userCreated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Add logging or throw whatever exceptions needed
                throw;
            }

        }
        return userCreated;
    }
}
```

Add this to Application_Start

```
Database.SetInitializer(new OAuthNoMigrateInitializer());
```

Note: I like to create a method that checks for users and is called from the Application_Start.  Initialization is started the first time you make a call to the DB, this does it.

```
private static void ViewDb()
    {
        using (var context = new OAuthNoMigrateContext())
        {
            var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName.StartsWith("T"));
        }
    }
```

That calls this initializer

```
public class OAuthNoMigrateInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OAuthNoMigrateContext>
{
    private readonly CustomSimpleMembershipProvider _provider = new CustomSimpleMembershipProvider();

    protected override sealed void Seed(OAuthNoMigrateContext context)
    {
        //Initialize UserProfile
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        AddUsers(context);
    }

    private void AddUsers(OAuthNoMigrateContext context)
    {
        if (WebSecurity.UserExists("username")) return;

        var user = new User
        {
            FirstName = "FName",
            LastName = "LName"
        };

        _provider.CreateUser("username", "password", user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to comment out or remove the [InitializeSimpleMembership] in the AccountController.cs since you are already initializing in the seed.